# how to optimize inner join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, inner-join, flip

I have two tabels.[They are in Heidi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA3fN.png)
I need table like:[Rezult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZFPR.png)

I try next SELECT:

```
    SELECT  accounts.name, accounts.account_id,date,  
  (case  when accounts.account_id = results.account_id then date  end) AS Dat,  
results.account_id 
FROM results 
INNER JOIN accounts 
group by date,dat,name 
order by accounts.account_id ,date
```

But I have unneeded fields. help get rid of them.

**Additionally:**
I must show  table like this:

```
--------------------01.2010----02.2010-----03.2010---nextDate

Revenues ----------'x'------------'x'---------'null'---------------------

Personal Costs-----'x'------------'x'---------'x'---------------------

Amortisation---------'x'------------'x'---------'null'---------------------

Summa---------------'3x'-----------'3x'---------'1x'---------------------
```

I use next select:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(revenues SEPARATOR ';')as Renenues, 
GROUP_CONCAT(personal  SEPARATOR ';')as Personal, 
GROUP_CONCAT(amortisation  SEPARATOR ';')as Amortisation
from (SELECT  date, 
sum(case  when accounts.account_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as revenues,
sum(case  when accounts.account_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as personal ,
sum(case  when  accounts.account_id = 3 then 1 else 0  end) as amortisation
from accounts
left JOIN results on accounts.account_id = results.account_id
group by date
) t
UNION ALL
SELECT
sum(case  when results.account_id = 1 then 1 ELSE 0  end) ,
sum(case  when results.account_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) ,
sum(case  when  results.account_id = 3 then 1 else 0  end) 
 from results
```

Then I will show table row from my string: 'GROUP_CONCAT'.
Possible to make such that SELECT without knowing the number of  'accounts.account_id' or optimize this SELECT? 
I tried the first SELECT but get a lot of unnecessary information.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your query to be like

```
SELECT  accounts.name, 
accounts.account_id as accounts_account_id,
accounts.date,  
results.account_id  as results_account_id
FROM results 
LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.account_id = results.account_id
group by accounts.date,accounts.name 
order by accounts.account_id ,accounts.date;
```

Comment: it's doesn't work. I need 'Null' volue when there is no 'date' for some accounts.name

Comment: @user3205692, then just change from INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN

Comment: @user3205692, in that case use a LEFT OUTER JOIN. See edit in answer.